# write string in for loop in string

Tags: javascript

I want to write a string inside a loop, in a string. But I get an error ...

I tried this:

```
var string = "\
    <select>\
    "
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            "\
                <option></option>\
            "
        }
    "\
    </select>\
";
```

I want to have the following output:

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
    <option></option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the error? There are several options here, such as string concatenation or template literals. Do you know how to use either of those?

Comment: Does the string have to be formatted in that way, or do you just want a string of elements without the spacing?

Answer (score 1):

loops inside of string is not valid syntax, you need to perform concatenation by yourself:

```js
var string = "<select>";
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    string += "<option></option>";
}
string += "</select>";
console.log(string);
```

Comment: _"loops inside of string is not valid syntax"_: if you're using template strings you can iterate over data.

Comment: @Andy can you give example of for loop inside of template string? or you meant define function with loop inside?

Comment: Sure. [This takes an array of objects and `map`s over them](https://jsfiddle.net/s86vfz9w/) to produce some options (for example). @IłyaBursov